# Difference : 'so on' and 'so forth'

Tags: word-choice, phrase-meaning, difference

Are there any differences between '**so on**' and '**so forth**'?

What are the cases when I should use '**so on**' and what are the cases when I should use '**so forth**'?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Do you mean *'so on and so forth'* or both separate -*so on*, *so forth.*

The latter case will create some confusion as it's actually *and so forth*.

> *and so forth* - many meanings [here](http://www.yourdictionary.com/and-so-forth).

Likewise, *so on* would also take *and*

> *[and so on](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/and+so+on)* - continuing in the same way

In addition, *and so on and so forth* also exists as an idiom!

> *[so on and so forth](http://www.usingenglish.com/reference/idioms/so+on+and+so+forth.html)* -
>   And so on and so forth mean the same as etcetera (etc.)

There's no difference as such. All mentioned above are used to mean ...go on..similar thing... etc.

Answer (score 7):

Literally it would be "and so onwards".

[Forth](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/forth) and onwards (onward) are synonyms.

Both ”so on” and ”so forth” have the same meaning and are interchangeable, their usage is as et cetera.